# Is it possible to access block.number inside a view function?

Tags: solidity, view

I have a transactional function that can only be called every few blocks, and I would like to create a view function that returns the number of blocks until the transactional function can be called again, in other words, current block minus block number of the last time the transactional function was called (which I keep track of in my contract state).

Is it possible to access the block.number inside a view function or can I only access it in a transactional function?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to just try it rather than write this question?

Comment: If everybody tries every undocumented feature, no wonder why those languages and frameworks are so poorly documented.

Comment: Most team accept pull request to add more documentation.

Answer (score 2):

So indeed, after having tried this undocumented feature, I can confirm it is possible.